# Update error: why?

Tags: updating

I have just set up a Drupal 7 website. Being new to Drupal 7, I am not sure why I get this error whenever I try to create an article or blog:

> Error loading meta tag data, do the /?q=update.php">database updates need to be ran?

I am not able to even add a page to the menu. I am also not able to enable clean URLs on the site. Can anyone tell me what I may be missing?

Comment: It's always a good idea to tell us what non-core modules you've installed when encountering an error. It may be that you need to run a database update, and wait a long time: http://drupal.org/node/1844638

Answer (score 5):

Have you run update.php? If not, you need to do this.

There is a link to run it on the Reports -> Status Reports admin page if you need to run it.

If this does not work, and if this is a fresh, unused install of Drupal 7, and you get this error, my suggestion is to start from scratch with just the core, and then install modules one by one, and test after each, to identify the module that triggers this.

To enable clean URLs you need to set up your web server to allow rewrite rules.

If you run Apcahe2, in order to have clean URLs with Drupal, it is necessary to enable an extension to the Apache web-server known as `mod_rewrite`. You do this with the following shell command:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

Then navigate to /etc/apache2/sites-available and edit the file named `default`. Locate the following block of text:

```
<Directory /var/www>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

And change the AllowOverride directive to:

```
<Directory /var/www>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all 
</Directory>
```

When done, restart Apache.

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

(The above example is assuming you're running a standard Apache configuration on Ubuntu ver. 12. YMMV, and you may have to dig out the documentation for your system to see how to do something similar.)